# DSpace: Items only appear in Discovery after moving to another collection

Tags: move, items, dspace

I moved all the items from a collection to another. However, these items, on the source collection,didn't appear on the discovery. After the move, these same items appeared on the destination collection. Why these items didn't appear at the source collection before the move?

Still before the move: If I get these item's handle and try to access on a browser it works. Should it be a problem on discovery index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move items between collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578227/move-items-between-collections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 causes for this issue.

1. the items need to be re-indexed.  Depending on how the move was performed, the index may not have been updated.
2. If you are using XMLUI, the cocoon cache needs to be cleared

Here is my recommendation.

1. Since this is quick, clear the cocoon cache from the Admin->Control Panel->Java Information page.
2. It that does not resolve the issue, re-build your discovery index by running [dspace-install]/bin/dspace index-discovery -b

The re-index can take a while a while to complete.  User search results will be impacted during the re-index process.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what terrywb said in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756832/72625) to this question, in order for automatic re-indexing to work, these things also need to be done:

- The "discovery" event consumer must be enabled in your dspace.cfg
- The solr data directory for the discovery index (`[dspace]/solr/search/data`) needs to be owned by the same user that tomcat runs under, so that the tomcat user can add/change/delete files and subdirectories

Automatic re-indexing should be triggered whenever you move items through the user interface or via bulk metadata editing.

Honestly, we've [been through this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578227/move-items-between-collections) -- it would be helpful if you could give us more information on your original question rather than posting a new one.

Comment: The point is that on that question the index was not showing the items after the move. On this question, the items are not shown on a certain collection and then after move these items to another collection, they are shown on this new collection So my question is: why weren't these items shown on the old collection?

Comment: Ah right, got it now. Well, I'm guessing the answer was that they weren't indexed before the move because you weren't succeeding in triggering the reindex. You must have performed the move in a way that _did_ successfully trigger the reindex. But it's hard to know without more information on what exactly you actually did.

Comment: Ok! This repo is a bit messy because it's a test repository. The repository in production is working properly I guess. So I won't waste your times by trying to find the error on a test repository. First I will organize it then if the problems persist I contact you!